# python split dataframe subset with from to condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have dataframe and I have to split in subset with this conditions:

start split: c = 1 
end split:   c = -1

example:

```
 a         b    c
False   False   
False   False  -1 
False   False   
True    False   1  start first subset
False   False   
False   False   1
False   False   1
False   False   
False   False   1
False   False   
False   False   1
False   False   
False   True   -1 end of first subset
False   False   
False   False   
False   True   -1
False   False   
False   False   
True    False   1 start second subset
False   False  -1 end of second subset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution, although I'm not sure if it's the most efficient approach. This basically uses cumsum and some and/or logic.

````
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'c': [np.nan, 1, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan,
                         -1, np.nan, np.nan, 1, np.nan, np.nan,
                         1, 1, np.nan, -1, -1, 1, -1]})

      c
0   NaN
1   1.0
2   NaN
3   1.0
4   NaN
5   NaN
6  -1.0
7   NaN
8   NaN
9   1.0
10  NaN
11  NaN
12  1.0
13  1.0
14  NaN
15 -1.0
16 -1.0
17  1.0
18 -1.0

(
    df
    .assign(
    start_end=lambda df: df.index.isin(
        df
        .loc[lambda df: df.c.isin([1,-1])]
        .loc[lambda df: df.c.shift(1,fill_value=0)!=df.c]
        .index),
    start=lambda df: np.where(np.logical_and(df.start_end==True,df.c==1),1,0),
    end=lambda df: np.where(np.logical_and(df.start_end==True,df.c==-1),1,0),
    subset=lambda df: np.where(df.start.cumsum() != df.end.shift(1, fill_value=0).cumsum(),
                               df.start.cumsum(),
                               0)
    )
    .drop(columns=['start_end','start','end'])
)

      c  subset
0   NaN       0
1   1.0       1
2   NaN       1
3   1.0       1
4   NaN       1
5   NaN       1
6  -1.0       1
7   NaN       0
8   NaN       0
9   1.0       2
10  NaN       2
11  NaN       2
12  1.0       2
13  1.0       2
14  NaN       2
15 -1.0       2
16 -1.0       0
17  1.0       3
18 -1.0       3
```
````

Comment: it works, but not completly: this is an extract of output: https://pastebin.com/fPMECBRY Can you help me to fix? It consider also the "1"s through the subset (before "-1"). Thanks a lot!

Comment: I guess I fixed it, however this looks a lot more complicated than what it's supposed to do. But: everything takes place in one pipeline and we avoid creating weird intermediate dataframes (df1, df2, df3) that won't be of any valuable use.

Comment: I found a little bug: if the first value of "c" is -1 the algorithm not work! So before execute your code i put this simple line:                                                                  df['c'] = df['c'].loc[df[df['c'] == 1].first_valid_index():]